# How to convert the binary code from the rest api to a excel file in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, excel, api, binary, byte

I am getting the file content as binary or byte array(FROM THE REST API) and want to convert this into a excel file and download it in client side using angular.js , but don't know how  to do it. Can anyone help me out here.

Also im attaching the code here , .xls file is getting downloaded but after opening it file content remains same binary/byte content that im getting from a api response , instead of the actual file content. Can anyone tell what i am missing here.  Or how i can convert/read the response to actual format.  Any help is much appreciated as im completely stuck.

```
$http.get(__env.apiUrl+"/UserSurvey/GetTrackingReport?surveyId="+$rootScope.surveysummaryID,{headers:{"Content-type":"application/json",'sessionID':$rootScope.token}}).then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
             var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
              if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
              }
              else {
                  var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  window.open(objectUrl);
              }

        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faced the same issue , I had missed out on conversion of the unsignedint value and passes the same to the blob object and it works!!

```
   $http.get(__env.apiUrl+"/UserSurvey/GetTrackingReport?surveyId="+$rootScope.surveysummaryID,{headers:{"Content-type":"application/json",'sessionID':$rootScope.token,'Accept': "application/vnd.ms-excel"}}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(function(response){
              var dec = window.atob(response.data);
              var myArr = new Uint8Array(dec.length)
              for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(dec).length; i++){
                  myArr[i] = dec.charCodeAt(i);
              }
              var blob = new Blob([myArr], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
              if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob);
              }
              else {
                  var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  window.open(objectUrl);
              }
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Hope this helps someone!!